# continuing userActivity not working when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, nsuseractivity

I am trying to implement universal linking in swift, but am having an issue when the app is not already opened. It works perfectly fine when the app has been previously opened, it will navigate to the proper view controller. When the app has not been opened, it will not navigate to the desired view controller, I think it has something to do with the root view controller, but am not positive. Has anyone dealt with the same issues?

in `AppDelegate`

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        
        let navigator = Navigator()
        if let url = userActivity.webpageURL {
            navigator.getDesination(for: url)
        }
     }
```

the `getDestination` function will eventually trigger the following code eventually:

```
func openPostVC(id: Int, showComment: Bool, commentID: Int?) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return }
        if let _ = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? BannedViewController { return }
        
        let postStoryboard = UIStoryboard.singlePost
        let singlePostVC = postStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! SinglePostViewController
        singlePostVC.shouldNavigateToHomeAction = {
            self.loadMainStoryboard()
        }
        
        let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: singlePostVC)
        navigationVC.view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationVC
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a scene delegate?

Comment: No SceneDelegate, it's an older project

Comment: You should probably add one. That will lay you get the right messages in iOS 13 and later. Or just get the url in DidFinishLaunching.

Comment: By the way here’s an article about how to debug. https://www.biteinteractive.com/tricks-for-testing-external-links/